# JSON Mapping Issue

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to map json input but its not being recognised. The request is still shown as null. Not really sure why this is happening. I tried different jsons but its the same. Can anyone please tell why this is happening. The other requests are working fine. Only the list is not working.

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, path = "/addQuestionOptions")
    public void addQuestionOptions(@RequestBody QuestionOptionsRequest questionOptionsRequest,
                                   @RequestParam("questionId") int questionId) {
        questionService.addQuestionOptions(questionOptionsRequest, questionId);
    }
```

Request

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class QuestionOptionsRequest {

    private List<QuestionOption> questionOptions;

    public List<QuestionOption> getQuestionOptions() {
        return questionOptions;
    }

    public void setQuestionOptions(List<QuestionOption> questionOptions) {
        this.questionOptions = questionOptions;
    }   
}
```

QuestionOption

```
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"quesiton"})
public class QuestionOption {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private String id;

    private String questionOptionId;

    private String questionOption;

    public Question getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public void setQuestion(Question question) {
        this.question = question;
    }

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId
    private Question question;

    public void setQuestionOptionId(String QuestionOptionId)
    {
        this.questionOptionId = QuestionOptionId;
    }

    public void setQuestionOption(String QuestionOption)
    {
        this.questionOption = QuestionOption;
    }

    public String getQuestionOption()
    {
        return this.questionOption;
    }

    public String getQuestionOptionId()
    {
        return this.questionOptionId;
    }

}
```

JSON

```
{ 
    "questionOption" : [
    {
        "questionOptionId" : "1",
        "questionOption" : "A"
    },
    {
        "questionOptionId" : "2",
        "questionOption" : "B"
    },
    {
        "questionOptionId" : "3",
        "questionOption" : "C"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Your request will throws exception. Are you sure it just read null instead of exception?

Comment: Just read null. No excretion

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by changing the key to 'questionOptions'. This works. Lesson Learnt!!